# MySQL Count Noses

Tags: mysql, count

I would like to count visitors and count noses.
Here is the table

```
UID | VisitDate  | VisitTime
-----------------------------
11  | 2014-12-11 | 10:18
12  | 2014-12-11 | 11:42
13  | 2014-12-11 | 12:15
11  | 2014-12-11 | 13:31
14  | 2014-12-12 | 07:19
12  | 2014-12-13 | 09:18
12  | 2014-12-13 | 16:55
```

I have solved the count visitors that use the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS visitors FROM record WHERE VisitDate >= '2014-12-11' AND VisitDate <= '2014-12-13'
```

And result here:

```
visitors
---------
7
```

But I can't solve the count noses.
If a visitor came here twice or more in the same day, it should count once only.

From the table above, UID 11 came twice in 2014-12-11 and UID 12 came twice in 2014-12-13 so just count them once only. By all means: I can get 5 in result.

Comment: First of all, amend your schema so that date and time are in the same column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT** I updated the query and added sql fiddle markdown.

You have to first group by visit date, which condenses each visitor's visits to one per day. Next, you count the number of visitors.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4309/11)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table record(
  UID int,
  VisitDate date,
  VisitTime time
  );


insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 11 , '2014-12-11', '10:18';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 12  , '2014-12-11', '11:42';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 13  , '2014-12-11', '12:15';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 11 , '2014-12-11', '13:31';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 14 ,'2014-12-12', '07:19';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 12  ,'2014-12-13', '09:18';

insert into record(UID, VisitDate, VisitTime)
select 12 , '2014-12-13', '16:55';
```

**Query 1**:

```
     select count(UID) as noses
     from (
        SELECT UID,  VisitDate
           FROM record 
             WHERE VisitDate >= '2014-12-11' AND VisitDate <= '2014-12-13'
             Group by uid, VisitDate
   ) visitors
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4309/11/0)**:

```
| NOSES |
|-------|
|     5 |
```

Comment: Got 2, 1, 2, 1, 1 in result. Same as above query but splitted into each UIDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT UID) visitors FROM record WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN '2014-12-11' AND '2014-12-13' GROUP BY (DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **HAVING CLUASE**

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS visitors FROM record  having  VisitDate >= '2014-12-11' AND VisitDate <= '2014-12-13'and COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: You have a syntax error.

Do you mean: SELECT COUNT(*) AS visitors FROM record WHERE visitdate BETWEEN '2014-12-11' AND '2014-12-13' HAVING COUNT(*) = 1?

But it returns zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS record;

 create table record
   ( UID int not null
   , VisitDate datetime not null
   , PRIMARY KEY(UID,VisitDate)
   );


 insert into record(UID, VisitDate) VALUES
 (11 , '2014-12-11 10:18:00'),
 (12 , '2014-12-11 11:42:00'),
 (13 , '2014-12-11 12:15:00'),
 (11 , '2014-12-11 13:31:00'),
 (14 , '2014-12-12 07:19:00'),
 (12 , '2014-12-13 09:18:00'),
 (12 , '2014-12-13 16:55:00');

 SELECT SUM(total) grand_total 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) total 
          FROM record 
         WHERE visitdate BETWEEN '2014-12-11 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-12 23:59:00'
         GROUP 
            BY visitdate
      ) x;
```